# Передача координат закрашенных пикселей в JSON

Tags: javascript, python, canvas, flask

Имеется графический редактор на javascript. Суть такова: человек делает произвольный рисунок, массив закрашенных пикселей должен передаться на сервер  для последующего возвращения новых точек с целью анимации. Графический редактор выполняет роль среды моделирования, где человек в форме заполняет данные и рисует в поле область начального расположения вещества. Далее выполняются расчеты концентраций на сервере и анимация распространения концентрации на поле. Можно ли как-то
записать массивы закрашенных пикселей в JSON? Или есть другие способы передачи координат? Сервер Python, Flask. Заранее благодарен.

[image: Графический редактор]

Comment: Можно. Существуют

Comment: `let pixelsData = canvas.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data`